# Exclude non-working days in days to borrow

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am current making a library management system. The thing is the library is only open in working days and closed in weekends.

Ex. Days to borrow = 10
Borrow date = 03/16/15(Monday) 
Instead of having the return date in 03/26/15(Thursday) the return date will be in 03/30/15(Monday) Non-working days are already excluded.

Here is my code...

```
 int days = 0;
 DateTime deyt = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime dt = deyt.AddDays(int.Parse(textBox3.Text));
 DateTime span = deyt;
 while (span <= dt)
 {
     if (span.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && span.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
     {
          days++;
          bdate.Text = deyt.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
          rdate.Text = span.AddDays(days).ToString("MM/dd/yy");
     }
     span = span.AddDays(1);
 }
```

When i input 2 in days to borrow, it executes perfectly, but when i input 3 or more, the date to return increments to 2 instead of 1. 
Thank you very much in advance SO!

Comment: I strongly suggest a calendar table. Holidays are more complicated that just excluding weekends. BTW It is nearly always best to use year, month, day if you cannot use a date.

Comment: I dont plan on also excluding holidays.